# New To FitNesse - How can i verify that my database query has successful run

Tags: fitnesse, dbfit

I am using dbFit.Oracle.
I am using FitNesse to write an acceptance test making API calls.
How can I verify that my Oracle db query in the test case has run successfully? I am trying to update some column in the database, but no success.
Or are there any preconditions I need to take care of before running the query?

This is my query:

```
|update  |                   d3_account     |
|Statement_preference_type= |SOURCE_ACCOUNT_ID|
|PAPER   |                  | IDAP111112000|
```

Answer (score 1):

By default DbFit is using autocommit=false mode. You need to set it to true

or explicitly run commit command using DBFIt